# Redux state from actions and reducers does not show in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an actions file called menu that uses axios to get JSON data from a backend API. I then have reducers which are called in a MainMenu.js file which gets the data. All of the data is shown in the Redux devtools. However I am only able to access the data I have in intitialState. There should be an array of three items but it only shows the first one in intitialState. The data from the reducers does not show up when I try to console.log it. So obviously I would not be able to render it to the DOM.

[image: Redux Dev Tools]
[image: Javascript Console]

***actions/menu.js***

```js
import { ADD_PRODUCT, GET_PRODUCTS, GET_PRODUCT } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getProducts = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:8080/menu')
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            const data = response.data;
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PRODUCTS,
                payload: { data },
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

export const getProduct = (product) => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/menu/${product}`)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            const data = response.data;
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PRODUCT,
                payload: { data },
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

***reducers/index.js***

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import menu from './menu';

export default combineReducers({ menu });
```

***reducers/menu.js***

```js
import { GET_PRODUCTS, GET_PRODUCT } from '../actions/types';

const intitialState = [
    {
        test: 'Test',
    },
];

export default function (state = intitialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case GET_PRODUCTS:
            return [...state, payload];
        case GET_PRODUCT:
            return [...state, payload];
        default:
            return [...state];
    }
}
```

***components/MainMenu.js***

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts, getProduct } from '../actions/menu';

const MainMenu = ({ getProducts, getProduct, menu }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        getProduct('b4bc2e28-21a3-47ea-ba3b-6bad40b35504');
        console.log(menu);
    }, []);
    return <Fragment></Fragment>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    menu: state,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts, getProduct })(MainMenu);
```

Comment: `getProducts` and `getProduct` are async and you're logging synchronously before they're completed. If you log outside of `useEffect`, you should see each state value at each step of the process.

Comment: Okay thanks that worked. I am just figuring out how to get the data to show up in the DOM so that I can map over it. Trying the ternary operator to check for when the data has loaded.

Comment: Yep, you're on the right path! Your component needs to handle every possible case for menu, so maybe show a loading screen while it's the initial value, then swap to the real data. Something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a working solution using the ternary operator. First a check is made to see if all of the elements in the array have loaded. If they have not all loaded then a data not loaded div is displayed. Otherwise the data is rendered to the DOM.

```js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts, getProduct } from '../actions/menu';

const MainMenu = ({ getProducts, getProduct, menu }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        getProduct('b4bc2e28-21a3-47ea-ba3b-6bad40b35504');
    }, []);
    if (menu.length <= 2) {
        console.log('Data Not Loaded');
    } else {
        console.log('Data', menu[2].data.name);
    }
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>{menu.length <= 2 ? <div>Data not loaded</div> : <div>{menu[2].data.name}</div>}</div>
            <div>
                {menu.length <= 2 ? (
                    <div>Data not loaded</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        {menu[1].data.map((food) => (
                            <div>{food.name}</div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    menu: state.menu,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts, getProduct })(MainMenu);
```